# react native flatlist with and without pagination

Tags: react-native, pagination

In a chat application should pagination be implement in react native flatlist for chat list and messages list?
when and by how much can we see the performance benefits?

I tried loading array of 250 with(limiting 25 items per call) and without pagination I did not see any performance benefit react native flatlist handled both cases without performance hits.

I was expecting list with pagination to load faster.
Will pagination be beneficial for lets say 1000 item in a list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pagination is mostly about API support and optimization working with a network. For example, you have a cache on your API side for the last 10 items and it makes sense to show users the first time only these 10 items. For pagination, we use `onEndReached`.

If you are talking about UI performance you need to check the options `initialNumToRender` and `maxToRenderPerBatch`. From documentation:

`The maximum number of items to render in each incremental render batch. The more rendered at once, the better the fill rate, but responsiveness may suffer because rendering content may interfere with responding to button taps or other interactions.`

Also, don't forget about key list optimization:

- Use Key Extractor
- Avoid anonymous functions
- Memoize expensive component