# How to change state of FlatList item after rendered without refreshing other item on React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

There is a problem that all item refresh when `selectedIndex` changed because the `selectedIndex` is dependency of `renderItem`. I want to manage selectedIndex to globally cause just one or none item's detail have to enabled. Is there any solution to refresh just one item that `selectedIndex` pointed?

Here is my code

```js
interface ItemType {
  title: string;
  detail: string;
}

const FlatListTestScreen = () => {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState<number | null>(null);

  const data: ItemType[] = [
    { title: 'title1', detail: 'detail1' },
    { title: 'title2', detail: 'detail2' },
    { title: 'title3', detail: 'detail3' },
    { title: 'title4', detail: 'detail4' },
    { title: 'title5', detail: 'detail5' },
  ];

  const renderItem = useCallback<ListRenderItem<ItemType>>(
    ({ item, index }) => {
      console.log('render', index, selectedIndex === index);
      return (
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => {
            console.log('press', index);
            setSelectedIndex(index === selectedIndex ? null : index);
          }}>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          {selectedIndex === index && <Text>{item.detail}</Text>}
        </Pressable>
      );
    },
    [selectedIndex],
  );

  return <FlatList data={data} renderItem={renderItem} />;
};
```

```
 LOG  render 0 false
 LOG  render 1 false
 LOG  render 2 false
 LOG  render 3 false
 LOG  render 4 false
 LOG  press 1
 LOG  render 0 false <- unnecessary render
 LOG  render 1 true
 LOG  render 2 false <- unnecessary render
 LOG  render 3 false <- unnecessary render
 LOG  render 4 false <- unnecessary render
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer about FlatList optimization here: [react native flatlist with and without pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74429145/react-native-flatlist-with-and-without-pagination/74429746#74429746)

In your case, you need to provide `keyExtractor`

Also a very useful article from the official documentation:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration